# TypeError in Apps Script: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: google-apps-script

I have 2 sheets: "entireteam" and "Sheet9". They have the same number of columns (5). And their columns (A, B, C, D and E) have identical titles. The sheet "entireteam" is fully populated with data. But the sheet "Sheet9" is still empty. Now all I want to do with these 2 sheets is this: I want the search function that I´ve created to:

1. look for for all cells that contain the word `Cleveland`in the column B of the sheet "entireteam".
2. And copy the rows of these cells containing the word `Cleveland` into the sheet "Sheet9".

BUT: Whenever I run the code of my search function in the Google App Script editor, I get this error message about the **last line of my code**: "**TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined**".

Here is the entire code of my search function:

```
function doIt() {
var spreadsheet, targetSheet, sourceSheet, targetValues;
spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
targetSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Sheet9");
sourceSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("entireteam");
targetValues = sourceSheet.getRange(1, 1, 10, 5).getValues().filter(function (r) {
    return r[1] === 'Cleveland'
});
targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, targetValues.length, targetValues[0].length).setValues(targetValues);}
```

Can somebody please tell me what I am doing wrong and correct the mistake?

Thank you so much in advance for your help :)

Comment: The code worked for me.

Comment: Notes on when it is OK to ask for [urgent help](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/326590/12567365) on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Perhaps you don't realize that r[1] is column 2

Comment: @andrewjames - You are right. Typical rookie mistake. Sorry about that.

Comment: @Cooper - Yeah, you are so right! I just realized that r[1] is column 2. And now the script is working as intended. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: By the way, can somebody help me improve my search script in a way that it can 1) search for an unlimited number of cells containing the word ´Cleveland" in the same column or many other columns, 2) copy the related rows, and 3) copy them to another sheet? Any idea, @Cooper? Thank you ALL so much in advance!!!

Comment: That sounds like another question.

Comment: You can convert your last comment into a new question. But before you do so, you should research the problem and develop an attempt (code) that you can show us, explaining where you may be stuck. Don't forget to take the [tour] and read [ask] for more guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the comments fixed our issue, please mark is as done.

`r[1]` is the 2nd column, as it is the 2nd index because arrays are 0-indexed, i.e. they start at 0, then 1, and so on, whereas the table starts at column and row 1.

What you may also do is add a:
`if( !targetValues) return`
before your last line, so as to make sure there is a result before trying to write it to the sheet, as it would throw the said error.

Comment: thank you so much for putting me on the right track:). I truly appreciate it!!!